# css: auto center inner elements (with automargin)

Tags: html, css

I have such code:

```
<div class="first">
  <img class="inner n1">
  <img class="inner n2">
  <img class="inner n3">
</div>
```

and so it looks like:

[image]

can i strech automatically margin so:

[image]

so that first element is always on the left, second+n always in center and last one on the right side? (there could be 2...10 elements not only 3)

https://jsfiddle.net/9bbxL8w8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using flex-box.

```
.first{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9bbxL8w8/1/

Though beware of the supported browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: but what would be if height of yellow blocks will be dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between`

```css
.first{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display:flex;
}

.inner{
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner.n1{
  width: 40px;
}

.inner.n2{
  width: 60px;
}

.inner.n3{
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img class="inner n1">
  <img class="inner n2">
  <img class="inner n3">
</div>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Isn't that the same answer [Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761815/css-auto-center-inner-elements-with-automargin/34761866#34761866) posted 2 minute before you?

Comment: but what would be if height of yellow blocks will be dynamic?

Comment: You will not get any problem with different heights.

Comment: @Anonymous I was not see his answer may be I was late and I already upvote Jacob answer.